# NIMO April 2017 conditional probability / PIE system

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, inclusion-exclusion

> Two neighboring towns, MWMTown and NIMOTown, have a strange relationship with regard to weather. On a certain day, the probability that it is sunny in either town is $\frac{1}{23}$ greater than the probability of MWMTown being sunny, and the probability that it is sunny in MWMTown, given that it is sunny in NIMOTown, is $\frac{12}{23}$. [Find the probability that it is sunny in NIMOTown.]

Let the probability that it is sunny in MWMTown be $m$ and in NIMOTown be $n$. Then, the probability that MWMTown or NIMOTown is sunny is $m+n-m\cap n=\frac{1}{23}+m\implies n=\frac{1}{23}+p$, for $p=m\cap n$.

We're also given that $m | n = \frac{p}{n}=\frac{12}{23}\implies n=\frac{12}{23}p=\frac{1}{23}+p$, but this is obviously impossible.

I'm considering that I'm wrong about $m$ and $n$ being dependent, but it seems like they are because of the first condition; otherwise, I think my reasoning with the equations is fine. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Kooky problem.  Let $M$ and $N$ stand for the obvious events; then the two givens can be written as $P(M\text{ or }N)-P(M) = 1/23$ and $P(M \mid N) = 12/23$.  Note that you can rewrite the former as $P(\overline{M})-P(\overline{M}\text{ and }\overline{N}) = 1/23$; maybe you can get some mileage out of that.

Comment: Small typo, $n=\frac{23}{12}p$, so solve to get $n=\frac{1}{11}$.

Comment: Other than the mistake pointed out by @jlammy, your working is fine and you should get $n = 1/11, m = 12/23$.

Comment: To find $m$, please note that $p = m \times n$ or you could write the first one differently - $\, 1 - (1-m) \, (1-n) = m + \frac{1}{23}$

Comment: @jlammy But I don't see how, since $P(M | N) = P(M\cup N)/P(N)=12/23 \implies P(N)=12P(M\cup N)/23$.

Comment: $\frac{p}{n}=\frac{12}{23}\implies p=\frac{12}{23}n\implies n=\frac{23}{12}p$